# What does "I must have you dance" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "I must have you dance" mean? What kind of a sentence is it?

Comment: Could you provide some context?  I can't make much sense of the sentence without it.

Comment: Yes. There are number of things it could mean, in different contexts. Sentences do not mean anything by themselves -- only in a real context.

Comment: @Brendon: From Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen: ‘Come, Darcy,’ said he, ‘I must have you dance. I hate
to see you standing about by yourself in this stupid
manner. You had much better dance.’

Comment: @JohnMLawler: I added more context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I can make sense of that sentence is someone expressing his or her strong desire to induce the dancer to dance for him or her.  Although not all may agree, I think of this sort of construction as a part of high-society small talk.

> [polite conversation]
>   1: I quite enjoy the arts, don't you?
>   2: Yes, I certainly do.  As a matter of fact, I'm a dancer.
>   1: Wonderful! I own a dance hall, I must have you dance sometime.

Comment: I agree. I have seen this used in Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen.

Comment: Exactly, I read it in Pride and Prejudice.

Comment: Could you explain the structure, is the one you mentioned the same thing as what @Laure said?

Comment: Yes, this is the same thing laure said.  The quote you mentioned above is essentially a polite way of saying, "I don't want to see you sitting alone, go out and dance with someone."

Answer (score 6):

This is a pseudo-passive construction, I’ll have you know.

Comment: "Pseudo-passive"? How so? Looks pseudo-causitive to me.

Comment: @ColinFine: Or possibly pseudo-caustic.

Comment: despite my levity, that was a genuine request for explication. I can't see what's passive about the construction.

Comment: Passive has not applied. Full parsing [square brackets mark clauses] (parens mark arguments) is something like 

[WILL (I, [HAVE (I, [DANCE (U)])])]

Or, as we would say 200 years later, I want to see you dance.

Comment: @ColinFine: You're quite right. I was just being a pseud.

Answer (score 5):

The question here is on the polysemy of the verb *have*.
Followed by object pronoun + past participle or bare infinitive *have* can mean 
*make* or *oblige s.o. to*.
It implies  that the grammatical object (*you* in your example) is not entirely willing of the action expressed by the grammatical subject (*I* in your example).

"I'll have you do your homework, whether you like it or not." (says mum to son)

> "I'll have you executed on the spot."

(King of Hearts to Mad Hatter)